# How to implement a method that works for all struct type parameters?

Tags: rust

I have the following struct

```
struct Position<T> {
    ns: i32,
    we: i32,
    orientation: T
}
```

I'd like to have the following method without having to repeat its implementation for each and every type T I intend to use, since the method implementation does not actually depend on T I would think this is possible to do but I can't figure out how.

```
impl Position {
    fn distance(&self) -> i32 {
        self.ns.abs() + self.we.abs()
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a type parameter to the impl line but apparently that only works for a concrete type not for a type variable which is what I would need here to do what I want I think. I have tried something along the lines of `<_>` but no dice either.

Is this possible to do in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have methods on `Position` has apply to any `T`, you can place them in a `impl` that has no bounds:

```
impl<T> Position<T> {
    fn distance(&self) -> i32 {
        self.ns.abs() + self.we.abs()
    }
    
    // fn ....
}
```

Remember that you can have multiple `impl` blocks for a type. So if you have methods that require `T` to be bound, you can add

```
impl<T: Clone> Position<T> {
    // fn ...
}
```

Comment: oh ok I tried the <T> next to Position but I was missing the <T> next to impl. that was what I was missing thanks

Answer (score 2):

`T` is an intrinsic part of `Position`, so you need to `impl Position<T>`, but then T doesn't exist in the scope of the `impl` block (there is no intrinsic relationship between the `struct` and `impl` blocks, indeed they could use completely different parameter names), so you need to declare it:

```rust
impl<T> Position<T> {
    fn distance(&self) -> i32 {
        self.ns.abs() + self.we.abs()
    }
}
```